# Retrieving thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, hex

I've seen a few answers to this question for C# or PHP, but nothing yet that's helped me with Django, so apologies if I missed something obvious.

So, getting the thumbnailPhoto back through an LDAP query gets me a byte string of data in the format '\\xff\\xd8\\xff\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00\x00\\xff\\xdb\\x00C\\x00...' and so on and so forth. There's also a few weird parts, like '\\x16\\x16\\x181#%\\x1d(:3=<9387@H\\\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\\\egc\\xff'

Which is the better choice: converting the string to an Image and saving it to the Model's ImageField, or just saving the hex string and converting it in the view? Does it even matter?

And what's the appropriate way to handle this string? Do I need to replace the '\\x' before each hex value with a space, or does python do this on purpose?

Thanks for any help or pointers towards resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's good idea to cache results in ImageField. You cad do it like this

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
somemodel.image.save('{0}/photos/{1}.jpg'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, username), ContentFile(your_byte_string))
```

Comment: This works great! My only issue is that rather than writing to my media root into a "photos" folder, it's just saving right in the media folder base. Chaning the argument between {0} and {1} doesn't seem to alter anything, nor did appending to the end of MEDIA_ROOT. Still experimenting with it, but still accepting this because it answers the original question and all I've got left is a nitpick :P

Thank you!